# How to color textbox background color from database reading specific textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, database, background

I'm trying to color a textbox by reading an assigned color to a specific text.

This is my code:

```
using (MySQLHelper LeftCurrent = new MySQLHelper())
{
    string mysql = "Select BandColor as LeftSideCurrentBandColor from band WHERE PnBanda LIKE '" + textBoxLeftSideCurrentBandColor.Text + "'";

    MySqlCommand LeftCurrentCommand = LeftCurrent.GetCommand(mysql);
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = LeftCurrentCommand.ExecuteReader())

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        textBoxLeftSideCurrentBandColor.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(reader.GetString(0));
    }
```

But everytime I change the specified text the color won't change. How can I do this?

I have a textbox that fills with one of this values, N\A, 108/5010/0300, 108/5015/0200, 108/5015/0900.

When the textbox is filled with a value I want to color it with the specified color.

```
 1  N\A Red
 2  108/5010/0300   yellow
 3  108/5015/0200   DarkBlue
 4  108/5015/0900   white
```

Comment: Did You debug Your code ?

Comment: For every line you read.. you'll reset the colour of the same box....

Comment: yes, but i get nothing

Comment: Please debug and see what value you get for reader.GetString(0);

Comment: @imsome1 if i debug i get the color  DarkBlue if the textbox.text is 108/5015/0200 but if i choose the textbox to have diffrent value than 108/5015/0200 i get nothing

Comment: if it is empty you want to get RED? am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this without using loop because you are going to retrieve one value right

```
using (MySQLHelper LeftCurrent = new MySQLHelper())
{
  string mysql = "Select BandColor as LeftSideCurrentBandColor from band WHERE PnBanda LIKE '" + textBoxLeftSideCurrentBandColor.Text + "'";

  MySqlCommand LeftCurrentCommand = LeftCurrent.GetCommand(mysql);
  textBoxLeftSideCurrentBandColor.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName((LeftCurrentCommand.ExecuteOracleScalar() ?? "RED").ToString());
}
```

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: 'MySqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteOracleScalar' and no extension method 'ExecuteOracleScalar' accepting a first argument of type 'MySqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I made few changes

Comment: almost there, for all colors works exept N\A . i get this

Comment: "Select CuloareBanda as LeftSideCurrentBandColor from banda WHERE PnBanda LIKE 'N\\A'"

Comment: "{Name=Yellow, ARGB=(255, 255, 255, 0)}"
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I think it is because escaped \

Comment: It works. I changed the N\A in database and now it works

Comment: I changed if the query return nothing default color will be RED